# Pass variables between PHP and JSP with cURL

Tags: php, jsp, curl

I am working on an online shop payment system and have to deal with both JSP and PHP file. Here is the partial flow of the transaction:

1. PHP gets the encrypted string from $_REQUEST & passes it to JSP by cURL.
2. JSP decrypts it by calling corresponding API function.
3. JSP passes the decrypted variables back to PHP.
4. PHP receives the variables and updates the database.
5. PHP display response message.

---

Here is the PHP code:

```
<?php

$data = $_REQUEST['String'];

$url = "http://demo:8000/decrypt.jsp";
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "String=$data");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 

$result = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
//print $result;
//update database...

?>
```

I have done some testing and the encrypted string can be successfully passed to JSP by cURL. However, I have no idea how to pass the JSP variables back to the same PHP file.

Is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: `JSON` is the way. However, I would recommend to use either one: JSP or PHP. You can do everything with Java that you can do with PHP. So it does not make sense to increase unnecessary HTTP request.

Comment: Since my website is built with PHP and JSP is required only for the online payment system, I have to use them both. Anyway, can you elaborate more about how to use JSON to get the JSP variables from PHP?

Comment: Can not explain everything because it's too broad, start with learning about [JSON](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp) followed by [parsing in Java](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/parse-json-java/) and in [php](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_php.asp).